# gathering *ALL* links from given web page and then searching them by phrase

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am new to python language. As mentioned in the title, I am trying to obtain all the links from this web page:

Trying to find all links using python script from this page: https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://bankier.pl/

Links, which interests me the most are included in sections like this

year - month - week - day

The best option to find a specific phrase on all (or some range ) of years/months/weeks/days links, or at least to download the links and 'grep' it localy.

So far I have tried using beautifulSoup and selenium, but never was even close to gather what interests me the most. 
It seemed like the links were on "lower levels" and my script could not gather them.

Much appreciate your help.

Here are my attempts:

```
#############################
######bs4 script#############
#############################

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://bankier.pl/'

r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')  
links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
print(links)
```

and this:

```
#############################
######selenium script########
#############################

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/grzegorz/Documents/Techniczne/Skrypty/Python/Vulture/niewywalac/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://bankier.pl/')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="file"]/a')
len(links)
for link in links:
    link.get_attribute('href')
```

...but none of these prints the link I need to have ( so http://www.bankier.pl web page from specific date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now I can't see a way of getting the urls provided when you hover the mouse over a day, but by doing so you can at least get the first urls from each available scrapped day:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://bankier.pl/'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="wb-calendar"]
""")))


captures = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="wb- 
    calendar"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a
 """)

for capture in captures:
    print capture.get_attribute("href")

driver.quit()
```

Let me know if this helps.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply Lafa :) !

As completely new to selenium and python, I can see that Chrome window opens required address and web page is processing some request. After few seconds in my terminal I got following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 10, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="wb-calendar"]
NameError: name 'EC' is not defined

Comment: Got it fixed, by adding:
   " from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC"

 but now I have this one:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 10, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="wb-calendar"]
NameError: name **'By' is not defined**

Comment: I forgot to add a few imports.  `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as By` should do the trick. Let me know if that fixes everything.

Comment: Thank you, 
Now it gives following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 12, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="wb-calendar"]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'XPATH'

Comment: Please, take a look at the code from here https://gist.github.com/Lafaiet/950bf5f63a1460a8f5b7f13d4162ee25. Maybe my code is breaking when I post it in here.

Comment: Thank you !! That has solved the problem, I have modified it so that it takes each year as argument, but your concept did the trick :)

Comment: That's great! I'm super glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which was written in Java to get your respective output.

```
driver.get("https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://bankier.pl/");

        List<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<WebElement> link = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".month-week .month-day div div[class='captures'] a"));

        for(WebElement Url : link) {

            url.add(Url.getAttribute("href"));

        }

         *system.out.println(url.size())*   // get total link
          Iterator itr=url.iterator();  
          while(itr.hasNext()){  
           System.out.println(itr.next());  
          }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this language is completely not known to me. How should I start this script? I tried using node and rhino, but no success, both are showing errors.

Comment: When I run your command I get following error:

$ node script.js 
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/username/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3

Answer (score 0):

> ...but none of these prints the link I need

you are doing this:

```
for link in links:
    link.get_attribute('href')
```

which will print exactly nothing when running as a script.

did you mean something like this?:

```
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I've put this line, all this script does is opening this web page in Chrome. (I am using python 2.7.5 for this one).